# How can I reproduce CRAN errors for debian platform ?

Tags: r, gcc, debian, cran, rhdf5

I must correct some errors in my package antaresProcessing.

I want to reproduce these errors before.

[Here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_antaresProcessing.html), you can see CRAN Checks

I don't have debian OS.

I tried rhub, [you can see that the results are ok](https://builder.r-hub.io/status/antaresProcessing_0.14.tar.gz-be3e1166fb152936ffd0e712a259dbdf)

I tried to execute these functions, all are fine.

`rhub::check_for_cran(platform = 'debian-gcc-devel')
rhub::check_for_cran(platform = 'debian-gcc-patched')
rhub::check_for_cran(platform = 'debian-gcc-release')`

Comment: Have you checked to see if `rhdf5` is available? It appears to be a BioConductor package.